# In React js using panelon-react how to color change image 360 view

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, 360-panorama, 360-panorama-viewer

``Give me some suggestion, I have created a 360 view of an image in react using panelon-react, there are many objects inside the image, such as door, ac etc. So I have placed buttons above all these images, now if I click on that button the color picker opens, now if I select a color in the color picker the selected color should be the color of the door. So how do I do that?

My Github project link for view code
https://github.com/iamshivamshukla/360-view_image

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Use SVG format for images and using fill you can able to change colour

Comment: I have no idea how to do it, please explain me step by step

Answer (score 0):

to change the color of the image to blue, you can use the following CSS code:

```
.panelon-react img {
  filter: hue-rotate(180deg);
}
```

**This are steps to Follow:**

1. First, import the Panelon-React component and your image into your
   React project.
2. Next, add the Panelon-React component to your JSX code and pass in
   the image as a prop.
3. To change the color of the image, you'll need to modify the CSS
   styles. You can do this by targeting the image element and adding a
   CSS filter property.
4. The filter property can take various values, including brightness,
   contrast, hue-rotate, and saturation. To change the color of the
   image, you can use the hue-rotate value, which rotates the hue of
   the image by a specified angle.

Comment: I have many items inside the main image, like AC, door, curtain, so I just want to change the color of the door. So how can I change it?